# Can a Custom Wrapper Class for scikit-learn Model be Logged as a scikit-learn Model in MLflow?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mlflow

I am working with `MLflow` to log models in my machine learning projects and I have a question regarding logging custom wrapper classes that extend `scikit-learn` models.

I've created a custom wrapper class for the `IsolationForest` model from `scikit-learn.` Here's the code for my custom class:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest as OriginalIsolationForest

class IsolationForest(OriginalIsolationForest):
    def __init__(
        self,
        n_estimators=100,
        max_samples="auto",
        contamination="auto",
        max_features=1.0,
        bootstrap=False,
        n_jobs=None,
        random_state=None,
        verbose=0,
        warm_start=False,
    ):
        super().__init__(
            n_estimators=n_estimators,
            max_samples=max_samples,
            contamination=contamination,
            max_features=max_features,
            bootstrap=bootstrap,
            n_jobs=n_jobs,
            random_state=random_state,
            verbose=verbose,
            warm_start=warm_start,
        )

    def score_samples(self, X: pd.DataFrame):
        # Redefine the scoring function
        return -super().score_samples(X)
```

My question is: If I use this custom `IsolationForest` class in my project, can I still log it as a standard `scikit-learn` model in `MLflow`? Are there any additional steps or considerations I need to be aware of to ensure compatibility with `MLflow's` logging and tracking features?

I have also considered using a `pyfunc` flavour. But I'd rather the former option.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Maybe you can create a dummy experiment in `mlflow` and test it?